# Can an appleTV wake up an iMac to stream it's itunes

Tags: imac, sleep-wake, appletv, wake-on-lan

Let's say I have an imac with all of my videos on, which has been synced with itunes. If my computer has gone onto standby, but I am in the other room with an appleTV and want to watch something from itunes on there, will the appleTV be able to wake up my imac automatically and play the content?

I haven't bought an appleTV yet but I am trying to have to avoid going into my office and turning on the imac everytime I want to watch some content on my appleTV.

I understand I can enable wake-on-lan on my imac but does the appleTV have the capability to do the same, wake it up and then stream it's content.

Comment: Just adding a note to make sure you know there's a new Apple TV coming later this month.

Comment: I am going to give this a try and confirm before posting an answer. I think it does, but I haven't done it in a while. @Tyson even with the new appleTV coming out this would still be a valid question. 32Gb or 64Gb is still limited space when looking at locally stored movies. That space only really helps for the apps - Apple still wants you to stream the content.

Comment: @JeffKranenburg my thought when I posted the comment was strictly with respect to the question, the new might do it if the old didn't.  And the thought don't rush to get the one available now until considering the new as well.

Comment: Fair call - I'll try with both when I come home tonight, but my day has only just started ;-)